# What does it means "[0]" at the end of the array designation?

Tags: javascript

I have these rows of code (source: Google Reference):

```
// log the subjects of the messages in the thread
var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];

var firstThread1 = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1);

var messages = firstThread.getMessages();
for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {   
Logger.log(messages[i].getSubject());
}
```

Why removing the `[0]` I'll get an Array (`firstThread1`), and with `[0]` I'll get an Object (`firstThread`)?

Thank you

Comment: [0] is the first object in an array. 0 is the first index.

Comment: It likes this: `[{},{},{}]`. So you get the first element of an array with `[0]`, which returns an obj for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [0] you get the first element of the array and that's why you get an Object. If you don't use it, you get the array itself.

Comment: @Idos but then, did the "question" really require a question?

Comment: @freedomn-m no it actually didn't, it's completely trivial.